# java android - working with file - still having old file

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to export my data into .xls file for the ShareActionProvider of ActionBarSherlock.

But I'm still receiving first file I've made. as I understand, I have to delete an old one first.

So I wrote :

```
 File file=new File(getCacheDir(), "Competition.xls");
 if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
    file = new File(getCacheDir(), "Competition.xls");
 }
```

but I still receive an old file instead of new one each time.

I know it must be simple but can't figure it out myself

Comment: Why you sure that you receive old file? You should try add current time to file name to see differences.

Comment: you should check the return value of delete() call to see whether the file is getting deleted.